# Should not Erasing from stl::list like this go to infinite loop?

Tags: c++, list, stl

Should not this code get into an infinite loop?

```
    list<int>val;
    val.push_back(0);
    list<int>::iterator iter,iterEnd;
    iter = val.begin();
    int i;
    for (; iter != val.end(); )
    {
        i = *iter;
        if(i==0)
        {
            val.erase(iter++);
        }
        else iter++;
    }
```

Since it has only one value after doing the erase and then incrementing the iterator, should not the iterator exceed the value val.end() and then fall into an infinite loop? But When I run it, it runs just fine! Can anyone explain please? Thanks.

Comment: `list::erase` doesn't invalidate any other iterators besides the one being deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example the `iter` is actually incremented before `std::list::erase` call and

> References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. Other references and iterators are not affected.[(cppreference)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase)

so when the deletion occurs, `iter` is already pointing to the next valid element.

Pseudocode equivalent to `lst.erase(iter++);`:

```
temp = iter
iter += 1
lst.erase(temp)
```

Comment: Then how is it deleting the first value? Since its pointing to the first value at the beginning then we increment it again before erasing. shouldn't the iterator be pointed to the second value(if any) when erase occurs and erases the second value?

Comment: Post-increment of the iterator returns the iterator before the incrementation, that's why the erase gets the right element.

Comment: Why didn't the program crash while running in debug mode. Isn't the iter invalid. I have seen such erase codes fail in case of vectors. Shouldn't the return value of erase function be used instead of incrementing the iter? Does the iter for list behaves differently from vector::iterators

Comment: @sajas yes, iters for lists behave differently from vectors due to the different memory layout for lists and vectors. From cppreference: (`std::vector::erase`) Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator.

Comment: Does your pseudocode work the same way if I use ++iter instead of iter++?

Comment: @kalkin No, the nature of pre- and post-incrementation is different. `lst.erase(++iter);` is equivalent to `iter +=1; lst.erase(iter);` with `iter` invalid afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

> after doing the erase and then incrementing the iterator

That's where you're wrong. It increments the iterator first (since function arguments are evaluated before calling the function), then erases the old value of the iterator.

Using post-increment (rather than incrementing in a separate step, `erase(iter); ++iter;`) is necessary since `erase` invalidates any iterators to the erased element. By incrementing first, `iter` itself is not invalidated, only the copy returned by the pre-increment.

Comment: s/pre-increment/post-increment/